# BigCartel Neat Theme - Home Page Changes

Tags: css

I was advised by BigCartel to visit here to seek help.

I am wondering if it would be possible to change the product image/links that appear on the home page to categories/collections. The layout can remain the same but instead of having links directly to products I'd like to have images/links to my website categories.

Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: Have you checked here first? https://help.bigcartel.com/. Strange they would advise you to come here to customise one of their own themes?

Comment: Yes I sought help from BigCartel first. They informed me it's not possible to amend the theme without editing the themes code - which goes beyond what they offer support with. At which point they advised:
You may have some luck posting those requests to a community based site where developers like to offer free help with coding questions: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bigcartel

Comment: Fair enough! Check here for other bigcartel questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bigcartel